# Calculating the probability of throwing five different numbers when you throw five six-sided dice

Tags: python, probability, dice

So I just started learning python 4 days ago from C++ and I got bit stuck on one coding challenge and is calculating the probability of throwing five different numbers when you throw five six-sided dice.
I did many researches, I tried many ways but still couldn't make it.
This is my piece of code:

```
def numOne(roll):
  return len([dice1 for dice1 in roll if dice1 == 1])
def numTwo(roll):
  return len([dice2 for dice2 in roll if dice2 == 2])
def numThree(roll):
  return len([dice3 for dice3 in roll if dice3 == 3])
def numFour(roll):
  return len([dice4 for dice4 in roll if dice4 == 4])
def numFive(roll):
  return len([dice5 for dice5 in roll if dice5 == 5])
def numSix(roll):
  return len([dice6 for dice6 in roll if dice6 == 6])

r = range(1,7)
sample = [(i,j,k,l,m) for i in r for j in r for k in r for l in r for m in r]
event1 = [roll for roll in sample if  numOne(roll) == 1]
event2 = [roll for roll in sample if  numTwo(roll) == 1]
event3 = [roll for roll in sample if  numThree(roll) == 1]
event4 = [roll for roll in sample if  numFour(roll) == 1]
event5 = [roll for roll in sample if  numFive(roll) == 1]
event6 = [roll for roll in sample if  numSix(roll) == 1]

print (len(event1)*len(event2)*len(event3)*len(event4)*len(event5)*len(event6), "/" ,len(sample))
```

or this:

```
def numOne(roll):
  return len([dice1 for dice1 in roll if dice1 == 1])
def numTwo(roll):
  return len([dice2 for dice2 in roll if dice2 == 2])
def numThree(roll):
  return len([dice3 for dice3 in roll if dice3 == 3])
def numFour(roll):
  return len([dice4 for dice4 in roll if dice4 == 4])
def numFive(roll):
  return len([dice5 for dice5 in roll if dice5 == 5])
def numSix(roll):
  return len([dice6 for dice6 in roll if dice6 == 6])

r = range(1,7)
sample = [(i,j,k,l,m) for i in r for j in r for k in r for l in r for m in r]
event = [roll for roll in sample if numOne(roll)==1 and numTwo(roll)==1 and 
numThree(roll)==1 and numFour(roll)==1 and numFive(roll)==1 or 
numSix(roll)==1]

print(len(event) / len(sample))
```

Both are wrong, of course. I'm not giving up yet, will edit out if I get to anything, meanwhile any tips or advise is appreciated.

Here is a much simpler example to explain what I'm trying to get to: Calculating the probability of having one six when we roll three dice:

```
def numsix(roll):
      return len([dice for dice in roll if dice == 6])

r = range(1,7)
sample = [(i,j,k,l) for i in r for j in r for k in r for l in r]
event = [roll for roll in sample if numsix(roll)==1]
print(len(event) / len(sample))
```

Comment: so do you have anything wrong with it then...?

Comment: Do you mean you want code to simulate rolling the dice and seeing the results? Your code is written in a very non-pythonic way - could you maybe add an example in plain English/pseudocode to explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: ok so, I'm trying to make the code simulate throwing 5 dice and list all the possibilities in `sample` then list out the `event` through a `for` loop with the "condition" of course and then at the end it prints the length of the event divided by the length of the sample (As you can see in the functions and sample). Here's a much easier version of the code where it calculates the probability of have exactly 1 six when throwing the dice 4 times:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to simulate the probability, especially with rolling dice, then you should be using a strategy called the [Monte Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) to include randomness.

Your code does not include any sort of randomness. Excluding the fact that both of your code samples calculate an incorrect result, it always calculates the **same** result. If no random sampling is included, then it implies that you already know in advance what is going to happen and your problem becomes a straight calculation.

Python is a very different animal than C++. You should not try to use your knowledge of an object-oriented language to write code using an interpretive programming language.

```
import random

same = 0
totalRolls = 100000

for i in range(1, totalRolls + 1):
    myRolls = []
    while len(myRolls) < 5:
        myRolls.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    if len(set(myRolls)) == 5:
        same += 1

print(same / totalRolls)
```

The above is an example of a solution that uses a Monte Carlo approach over 100,000 iterations. Each iterations 'rolls' 5 six-sided dice, and adds them to a list. It then converts the list into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and checks the length. Sets remove duplicates, so the only way to 'roll' five different numbers is for the set to have a length of 5. Otherwise, there was a duplicate.

I would read up on Python's documentation and then attempt to revise your code to make it work similar to the snippet above.

**Edit:** If you are looking for an average expected value using your code snippet, you can do something like this:

```
r = range(1,7)
sample = [(i,j,k,l,m) for i in r for j in r for k in r for l in r for m in r]

for i in sample:
    if len(set(i)) == 5:
        same1 += 1

print(same1 / len(sample))
```

...or you can use a mathematical approach: on the first roll there are 6 possible favored results. The next roll there will be 5 possible favored results, the roll after that there are 4 and so on and so on. This is `6!`. If you divide this number by the total number of outcomes per total number of rolls e.g. `6*6*6*6*6 = 6^6` you will also get your answer: `0.0925925925...`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! And yes, python is very different from C++. Anyways, your code prints out 0.09 which is the correct answer but one question: why did you set `totalRolls` equal to 100000? I changed it to `6**5` because am only rolling the dice 5 times and to make the program compile faster. Also, I wonder if Monte Carlo's simulation works for unordered selection without repetition for example drawing four aces in a set of card, what do you think?

Comment: @Midou35000 `totalRolls` can be any sufficiently large number. Unless you want to take the calculated average, you usually don't want to work with a small set of observations due to unusual patterns of randomness having more of an impact on your result. See [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). A Monte Carlo method can be used for most simulations that involve randomness

Comment: Cool! One last question, even though the `totalRolls` value is fixed, it shows different probability each time, can you explain please?

Comment: @Midou35000 would you expect **randomly** rolled dice to have the same result each time? If you want the "same result each time" you are probably looking for an [average, or expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)

Comment: I get it now. So we are not **calculating** here, we are **simulating**.  I need to calculate the EXACT probability, any tips?

Comment: I posted a much simpler example in my question, check it out